# JQgrid capture ADD/EDIT/Delete events

Tags: jquery, asp.net, wcf, jqgrid

I have a jqgrid currently iam able to load data from calling a wcf service. I also have add/edit/delete buttons which when selected show up respective UI. How/where should i handle this events. I would like to pass all the values user edited/entered pass it to a wcf service perform operations and refresh back grid. Can anyone please guide me how can i do this.

Answer (score 0):

The edit/add/delete function which ever you are using should have an ajax call to submit the input data to the server. You need to associate it with the server url and other available events of jqgrid. By default in case of success the modified data is added in the grid. However if there is a specific need to reload the grid after such operations with the data from the server , you can call a reload grid function after complete operation using afterComplete event and calling a reload grid event in it .

Something like below logic could be used

```
//This function is called when a particular row of data is edited in the table
    this.editRow = function(){
        try{
            var gr = jQuery("#mygrid").jqGrid('getGridParam','selrow'); 
            if( gr != null ) {
                jQuery("#mygrid").jqGrid('editGridRow',gr,
                    {
                        height:'auto',
                        width:'450',
                        reloadAfterSubmit:false,
                        url : editdata.action,
                        closeAfterEdit: true,
                        afterComplete:reloadGrid
                    }
                ); 
            }else {
                alert("Please Select Row"); 
            }
        }catch(e){
            alert(e);
        }

    };
```

Comment: JQgrid is opening a modal popup to edit or delete but how can i capture user entered values from modal popup and pass it to server for processing.

Comment: If its a normal dialog , u should be able to post the data to the server on submit and reload the grid.